# I want to join two tables and want column of both tables in result using linq

Tags: c#, linq

I want to join two tables and want column of both tables in result using linq

I have something like

```
var k = (from t in Uow.Transactions.GetAllWithReferences()
         join q in Uow.TransactionDetails.GetAll() on t.TransactionId equals q.TransactionId
         select t)
```

Instead of just t u wabt columns of both t and q

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use anonymous object to select all columns from both tables:

```
var k = from t in Uow.Transactions.GetAllWithReferences()
        join q in Uow.TransactionDetails.GetAll() 
             on t.TransactionId equals q.TransactionId
        select new { t.Column1, t.Column2, q.Colum3 };
```

Or just select both entities in anonymous object:

```
var k = from t in Uow.Transactions.GetAllWithReferences()
        join q in Uow.TransactionDetails.GetAll() 
             on t.TransactionId equals q.TransactionId
        select new { Transaction = t, Details = q };
```

Or even better - use [eager loading](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx) of details. Then code will look like:

```
var k = Uow.Transactions.GetAllIncluding(t => t.Details);
```

Comment: Error 1 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<AnonymousType#1>' to 'System.Linq.IQueryable<Edwards.MFG.FGS.Model.Transaction>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?) E:\fgs\trunk\FGS.Web\Controllers\AdminController.cs 93 30 FGS.Web

Comment: @ImranJawaid looks like you are trying to pass results of query execution to method which accepts `IQueryable<Transaction>` or assign them to variable of type `IQueryable<Transaction>`

Answer (score 1):

Using lambda syntax, create anonymous result containing both items:

```
   var joinResult =  Uow.Transactions.GetAllWithReferences()
          .Join(Uow.TransactionDetails.GetAll(), transaction => transaction,
                   details => details, (transaction, details) => new 
                                          { 
                                             Transaction = transaction,
                                             Details = details
                                          });
```